# Create a View From Max1 of One Column and the Max2 of Another if there are multiple Max1 for group

Tags: sql-server

From my table, I want to select for each project ID the ID with the latest deploymentDate and if there are two identical latest deployment dates for the same project ID, select the ID with the latest submittedOn datetime. So if my table looks like this:

```
    id  | projectId  |  deploymentDate  | submittedOn         |
    1   | 1          |  2017-01-02      | 2017-01-02 13:00:00 |
    2   | 1          |  2017-01-04      | 2017-01-04 11:00:00 |
    3   | 2          |  2017-01-06      | 2017-01-06 17:00:00 |
    4   | 2          |  2017-01-06      | 2017-01-01 12:00:00 |
    5   | 3          |  2017-01-02      | 2017-01-02 13:30:00 |
    6   | 3          |  2017-01-02      | 2017-01-05 15:00:00 |
    7   | 3          |  2017-01-02      | 2017-01-04 10:00:00 |
```

The desired rows are:

```
    id  | projectId  |  deploymentDate  | submittedOn         |
    2   | 1          |  2017-01-04      | 2017-01-04 11:00:00 |
    3   | 2          |  2017-01-06      | 2017-01-06 17:00:00 |
    6   | 3          |  2017-01-02      | 2017-01-05 15:00:00 |
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try the below.  Adjust the sorting in the row_number as needed.

```
select
    a.id,
    a.projectid,
    a.deploymentdate,
    a.submittedOn
from project a
inner join 
    (select 
            a.id,
            row_number() over (partition by projectid order by deploymentdate desc, submittedOn desc, id) as rid
    from project
    ) as b
    on b.id = a.id
    and b.rid = 1
```

Answer (score 0):

This would work:

```
select t.id, latest.*
from tab t join (
                    select projectid, max(deploymentdate) deploymentdate, max(submittedon) submittedon 
                    from tab 
                    group by projectid
                ) latest on t.projectid = latest.projectid and t.deploymentdate = latest.deploymentdate and t.submittedon = latest.submittedon
```

I found the latest based on the `project id` and then, joined with the source table to find the corresponding `id`.